# Trouble setting Environment variable ORACLE_HOME

Tags: oracle11g, database-connection, tnsping

I have a fresh installation of **Oracle 11g** client.

I am having trouble using `tnsping`. **It is giving an error:**

```
Message 3511 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNSTNS-0
05: Message 3505 not found; No message file for product=NETWORK, facility=TNS
```

**I have set the Environment variable for** `ORACLE_HOME` **as follows**:

```
D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN
```

I am not sure what should be exact path for ORACLE_HOME .

How to identify what is the exact path for ORACLE_HOME directory?

Is it   **D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1** ? `or`   **D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN**

Any suggestions or solutions ?

Comment: your ORACLE_HOME = D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN is incorrect.  It should be ORACLE_HOME=D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1.  See below comments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `ORACLE_HOME` should be `D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1`, assuming that is where you installed the software. The `BIN` directory under it should be in `PATH`.

[Read more about `ORACLE_HOME`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11857_01/em.111/e12255/oui2_manage_oracle_homes.htm)

The value [should be set in the registry by the installer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47798/intro.htm#NTDBI2641), along with other environment variables that have to be set manually in Unix.

Comment: Had the same issue and resolved by adding ORACLE_HOME, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

also just had this issue on a server, the oracle install seemed to have got a bit screwed, reinstalled, still same error, then discovered an erroneous space at the front of the env variable, space removed, server rebooted, all good again

Answer (score 1):

run > rededit > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>SOFTWARE > ORACLE> KEY_OraClient19Home1
and Edit the following

ORACLE_HOME browse to the folder where all the files are located(ASP.NET,bin etc)

you should be good to go!